# Comparing times in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time

I am using this code to compare times:

```
(time1.to_i - time2.to_i).abs < 5
```

The intention is that if two times are measured within 5 seconds from each other, they will be equal. I'm using it to compare updating of records, so 5 seconds is acceptable as a buffer, and stops the code returning `false` when the records are only splitseconds apart.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There's a gem called [time_difference](https://github.com/tmlee/time_difference). It isn't actively maintained, but it's easy to follow and incorporate. It gives you syntax like this: `TimeDifference.between(start_time, end_time).in_years`.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, you can subtract two [Time](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Time.html#method-i-2D) objects directly to get the difference in seconds. Rails provides some convenience helpers on integers to convert them into seconds as well:

```
(time1 - time2).abs < 5.seconds
```

If you know that `time2` always comes after `time1`, you can get rid of the `abs`:

```
time2 - time1 < 5.seconds
```